# Active Record find using conditional based on multi level association's attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am getting missing FROM clause error (shown below)

I want to find the entries whose associated reports' city is the same as the users' city, thus only showing relavant entries to users. So, if a user belongs to a city that a report does, the user should be shown the entries from that report.

I tried a few things, one being this scope in the Entry model:

```
scope :report_in_city, lambda { |user| joins(:report).where("report.city_id = ?", user.city_id) }
```

And if I call `Entry.report_in_city(user)`

I get this error:

```
SELECT "entries".* FROM "entries" INNER JOIN "reports" ON "reports"."id" = "entries"."report_id" WHERE (report.city_id = 1)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "report"
LINE 1: ... ON "reports"."id" = "entries"."report_id" WHERE (report.cit...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "entries".* FROM "entries" INNER JOIN "reports" ON "reports"."id" = "entries"."report_id" WHERE (report.city_id = 1)
```

I have a few models set up like this:

```
class Report
belongs_to user
belongs_to city
has_many entries

class Entry 
belongs_to report

class User 
has_many reports
belongs_to city

class City
has_many users
has_many reports
```

I am new to sql and would appreciate any advice on this query!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that string condition `"report.city_id = ?"` goes into the SQL, you have to use the table names. Rails is cute about going back and forth between plural and singular, but SQL only knows the table name `reports`. You can see that in the generated SQL like `ON "reports"."id" = "entries"."report_id"`. The table name is plural.

Try this:

```
"reports.city_id = ?"
```

or the Rails way:

```
joins(:report).where(:report => { :city_id => user.city_id })
```